# where is mongo server located in my pc

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have been working with meteor for few months .Now i got "unexpected mongo exit code" error .i was out of free disk space under .meteor/.local .
Where is this mongo db located in my local pc and how can  i delete or expand disk space.

Comment: `meteor reset` will reset your development database.

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax of dropDatabase() command is as follows:

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

This will delete the selected database. If you have not selected any database, then it will delete default 'test' database

Example:
First, check the list available databases by using the command show dbs

```
>show dbs
local      0.78125GB
mydb       0.23012GB
test       0.23012GB
>
```

If you want to delete new database , then dropDatabase() command would be as follows:

```
>use mydb
switched to db mydb
>db.dropDatabase()
>{ "dropped" : "mydb", "ok" : 1 }
>
```

Now check list of databases

```
>show dbs
local      0.78125GB
test       0.23012GB
>
```